# SQLAlchemy and Ambiguous Column name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, ambiguous

Ive had a good search on google but I cant seem to find an answer to this error in my case.

Im not making any joins, Im literally just trying to get all from this table.

All of the other queries work fine, but this seems to be messing up with this error:

```
InvalidRequestError: Ambiguous column name 'INMPTL_WIW_BATAM_STG.pers_no' in result set! try 'use_labels' option on select statement.
```

Model:

```
    batamStg = sa.Table("INMPTL_WIW_BATAM_STG", meta.metadata, 
    sa.Column("PERS_NO", sa.types.String(),primary_key=True),
    sa.Column("FIRST_NAME", sa.types.String()),
    sa.Column("LAST_NAME", sa.types.String()),
    sa.Column("KNOWN_AS", sa.types.String()),
    sa.Column("JOB_TITLE", sa.types.String()),
    sa.Column("MANAGER_NAME", sa.types.String()),
    sa.Column("MANAGER_ID", sa.types.String()),
    sa.Column("MANAGER_COST", sa.types.String()),
    autoload=True,
    autoload_with=engine)
```

View:

```
btm = meta.Session.query(model.BatamStaging).all();
```

There is only one column called Pers_no here and all of the primary keys are unique.

The same error also occurs if I try to set LAST_NAME as the primary key.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: I wouldn't know why it's doing that, but have you tried what it suggested and using "use_labels"?

Comment: Isnt the use_labels for select statements when you use execute()?

Comment: I believe you can also enable verbose debugging to see exactly what SQL statements SQLAlchemy is generating, which might help you figure out exactly why you're getting this error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My conjecture would be the **case-sensitivity** of column names when overriding columns which are reflected by using `autoload=True`. To verify, comment out all column definition and leave `autoload=True`. Then do the opposite.

See [Reflecting Database Objects - Overriding Reflected Columns](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#overriding-reflected-columns) of SA documentation for more information.

Comment: This seems like a likely case, although I cant seem to get them to work properly without autoload. If I manage to get it working Ill give you an update, thanks

Comment: Turns out you were right. This table was unlike all of the other tables in the database as it didnt stick to the naming schema and even though SQL Developer was showing the column names as capitalised, they must have been in lower case. I had assumed that sql developer showed them as they actually were and that sqlalchemy was case insensitve when mapping tables.